# How to loop through every combination of two characters in Batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, 7zip, winrar

I have a zip which is password protected. I want to run a batch file which will brute force attack on the zipped file and extract the files trying every password of **upto two letters only**.

Something like

```
FOR %%I in a to zz
7zip e test.7z -p"%%I"
```

Comment: @user2864740  thanks for the edit

Comment: You're welcome. The first impression is important - sometimes 'hacking' things get frowned upon and judged harshly even though there are interesting questions D:

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for %%I in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
     for %%J in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
          7z.exe x "D:/old.7z" -p"%%I%%J" 
))
pause
```

Though this is a long and filthy one It will work

Comment: Does batch support *nested* loops?

Comment: Yes. Ill try it out.

Comment: @SomethingDark I know it does but how can one do it in this case.

Comment: Add `for %%J in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (` n number of times before `7zip` and add n such `(` brackets after it,

Answer (score 2):

```
for %%I in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
  for %%J in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
    7z.exe x "D:/old.7z" -p"%%I%%J" 
  )
)
```

Comment: You should also include the lower case letters, since the question mentioned "a to zz" and not "A to ZZ".

Comment: @SomethinDark you're right, may I miss something, but I think the steps are on their way